# do-release-upgrade balks on broken python installation?

Tags: upgrade, python, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, but the upgrade fails each time.  It appears to be a problem with python, but I don't have a clue how to fix it.

Here's the apt.log file.

```
Log time: 2022-04-11 20:04:47.017579
Log time: 2022-04-11 20:05:08.103748
  MarkDelete python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK > FU=1
  MarkDelete python-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK > FU=1
  MarkDelete libpython-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK > FU=1
  MarkDelete libpython-stdlib:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK > FU=1
  MarkInstall python-is-python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-4 @un umN Ib > FU=1
  Installing python2 as Depends of python-is-python2
    MarkInstall python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uN Ib > FU=0
    Installing python2-minimal as PreDepends of python2
      MarkInstall python2-minimal:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uN > FU=0
    Installing libpython2-stdlib as Depends of python2
      MarkInstall libpython2-stdlib:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uN > FU=0
     Removing: python
      MarkDelete python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
  MarkInstall python-dev-is-python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-4 @un umN Ib > FU=1
  Installing python2-dev as Depends of python-dev-is-python2
    MarkInstall python2-dev:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uN Ib > FU=0
    Installing libpython2-dev as Depends of python2-dev
      MarkInstall libpython2-dev:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un uN > FU=0
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) python-support:amd64 < 1.0.15 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python-support:amd64 Depends on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR >
  Considering python-minimal:amd64 1 as a solution to python-support:amd64 5
  Added python-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing python-support:amd64 via keep of python-minimal:amd64
  MarkKeep python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR > FU=0
Investigating (0) python2-minimal:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib >
Broken python2-minimal:amd64 Breaks on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
  Considering python-minimal:amd64 1 as a solution to python2-minimal:amd64 4
  Added python-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing python2-minimal:amd64 via remove of python-minimal:amd64
  MarkDelete python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > FU=0
Investigating (1) python-support:amd64 < 1.0.15 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python-support:amd64 Depends on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR >
  Considering python-minimal:amd64 1 as a solution to python-support:amd64 5
  Added python-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing python-support:amd64 via keep of python-minimal:amd64
  MarkKeep python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR > FU=0
Investigating (1) python2-minimal:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib >
Broken python2-minimal:amd64 Breaks on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
  Considering python-minimal:amd64 1 as a solution to python2-minimal:amd64 4
  Added python-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing python2-minimal:amd64 via remove of python-minimal:amd64
  MarkDelete python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > FU=0
Investigating (2) python-support:amd64 < 1.0.15 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python-support:amd64 Depends on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR >
  Considering python-minimal:amd64 1 as a solution to python-support:amd64 5
  Added python-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing python-support:amd64 via keep of python-minimal:amd64
  MarkKeep python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gR > FU=0
Investigating (2) python2-minimal:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib >
Broken python2-minimal:amd64 Breaks on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
  Considering python-minimal:amd64 5 as a solution to python2-minimal:amd64 4
  MarkKeep python2-minimal:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back python2-minimal:amd64 rather than change python-minimal:amd64
Investigating (3) python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib >
Broken python2:amd64 PreDepends on python2-minimal:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
  Considering python2-minimal:amd64 4 as a solution to python2:amd64 7
  MarkKeep python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back python2:amd64 rather than change python2-minimal:amd64
Investigating (3) python-all:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib >
Broken python-all:amd64 Depends on python2:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
  Considering python2:amd64 7 as a solution to python-all:amd64 2
  MarkKeep python-all:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Re-Instated python2-minimal:amd64
  Re-Instated python2:amd64
  Re-Instated python-all:amd64
Investigating (4) python2-minimal:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib >
Broken python2-minimal:amd64 Breaks on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
  Considering python-minimal:amd64 5 as a solution to python2-minimal:amd64 4
  MarkKeep python2-minimal:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back python2-minimal:amd64 rather than change python-minimal:amd64
Investigating (5) python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib >
Broken python2:amd64 PreDepends on python2-minimal:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
  Considering python2-minimal:amd64 4 as a solution to python2:amd64 7
  MarkKeep python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back python2:amd64 rather than change python2-minimal:amd64
Investigating (5) python-all:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib >
Broken python-all:amd64 Depends on python2:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
  Considering python2:amd64 7 as a solution to python-all:amd64 2
  MarkKeep python-all:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing python-all:amd64 rather than change python2:amd64
  MarkDelete python-all:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (5) python2-dev:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib >
Broken python2-dev:amd64 Depends on python2:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
  Considering python2:amd64 7 as a solution to python2-dev:amd64 2
  MarkKeep python2-dev:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back python2-dev:amd64 rather than change python2:amd64
Investigating (5) python-all-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib >
Broken python-all-dev:amd64 Depends on python2:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umH > (= 2.7.17-2ubuntu4)
  Considering python2:amd64 7 as a solution to python-all-dev:amd64 1
  MarkKeep python-all-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
    Reinst Failed because of python2:amd64
  MarkKeep python-all-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing python-all-dev:amd64 rather than change python2:amd64
  MarkDelete python-all-dev:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (6) python-is-python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-4 @un pumN Ib >
Broken python-is-python2:amd64 Depends on python2:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umH >
  Considering python2:amd64 7 as a solution to python-is-python2:amd64 10000
Investigating (6) python-dev-is-python2:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-4 @un pumN Ib >
Broken python-dev-is-python2:amd64 Depends on python2-dev:amd64 < none | 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umH >
  Considering python2-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to python-dev-is-python2:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed because of python2:amd64
  MarkKeep python2-dev:amd64 < none -> 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 @un umN Ib > FU=0
Done
Log time: 2022-04-11 20:05:11.279568
```

When I run apt dist-upgrade or upgrade, I see no broken packages or other issues.  I've removed python-dev (on advice found elsewhere) but no effect.  I've also removed nodejs (similarly on advice found elsewhere), but no effect.

This is a lot like the bug described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1875523), but that thread says the issue was fixed and it's not looking that way on my end.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Kudos for checking your logs! Your output seems to suggest that the `python-support` package is a culprit. That package was removed before 16.04. Try removing it (`apt remove --simulate python-support`), If the simulation output shows nothing terrible, then remove the package for real. Then try do-release-upgrade again.

Comment: Do a "full-upgrade" (or "dist-upgrade" when using `apt-get`) first before attempting to upgrade the distribution.

Comment: user53...., that's very helpful!  I've removed the python-support package and run do-release-upgrade again.  The upgrade is currently running.  Thanks!

Comment: vanadium, I should have said -- I'd done apt-get dist-upgrade already.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it (twice, on different computers) by doing:

```
sudo apt remove python-dev
```

Then perform the `do-release-upgrade`.

The upgrade will almost complete, but at some point it will stop with broken packages.

Then, I edited by hand the file `/usr/share/pyzo/pyzo/yoton/clientserver.py` and changed the name of the parameter `async` on line 81 to `assync`, as well as two or three lines below where it was being used. Then I run `apt --fix-broken install` and `apt dist-upgrade`, and the upgrade completed correctly.